# Как пройти циклом for по ресурсу colors.xml

Tags: java, android, xml

Colors.xml:

```
<color name="b1">#ffb060</color>
<color name="b2">#feb060</color>
<color name="b3">#fdb060</color>
```

Как в основной активити сделать что-то подобное по смыслу

```
for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    tv6.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.b(i)));
}
```

`tv6` - это `TextView`.

**UPDATED**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <array name="my_colors">
            <item>#dd3b7fec</item>
            <item>#dded4545</item>
            <item>#dd6de947</item>
            <item>#ddf9e640</item>
            <item>#dd3b7fec</item>
            <item>#dded4545</item>
            <item>#dd6de947</item>
            <item>#ddf9e640</item>
            <item>#dd3b7fec</item>
            <item>#dded4545</item>
        </array>
    </resources>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте как-то так:

**src/main/res/values/array.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="b1">#ffb060</color>
    <color name="b2">#feb060</color>
    <color name="b3">#fdb060</color>

    <array name="my_colors">
        <item>@color/b1</item>
        <item>@color/b2</item>
        <item>@color/b3</item>
    </array>
</resources>
```

И затем в коде:

```
int[] myColors = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.my_colors);

int b1 = myColors[0];
tv6.setTextColor(b1);
```

Comment: насколько я помню, так не получится, поскольку в массив запишутся идентификаторы ресурсов `color`. В итоге будет массив идентификаторов, а не цветов :) но можно так сделать через TypedArray, который по идентификаторам будет доставать значения

Comment: @Jarvis_J попробуйте и проверьте.

Comment: да, тоже работает

Comment: Работает, только непонятно для чего 3 строчки  <color name="b1">#ffb060</color>. В item можно сразу цвета ставить.

Comment: @sapeg вы сначала создаёте ресурсы — цвета. Затем создаёте массив, куда помещаете ссылки на ресурсы, чтобы получать каждый ресурс не вручную каждый раз по id, а сразу пачкой в массиве. Создать сразу массив у вас не получится, записи ресурсов для каждого цвета нужно делать отдельно. Либо как в другом ответе, только один массив со строками, но тогда нужно будет делать преобразование. Выберите, что для вас удобнее.

Comment: В UPDATED написал как получилось.

Comment: @sapeg нет, вы смешали два разных варианта. Если вам удобнее просто hex цвета использовать и потом парсить в цвет, то скопируйте полностью код из другого ответа. Так, как написано у вас, работать не будет.

Comment: Так тоже заработал)

Comment: @sapeg, в документации есть ещё [**пример**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources#TypedArray) использования массива цветов (внизу).

Comment: woesss Ок. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте цвета через string-array:

```
  <string-array name="colors">
        <item>#dd3b7fec</item>
        <item>#dded4545</item>
        <item>#dd6de947</item>
        <item>#ddf9e640</item>
    </string-array>
```

И

```
String[] colorsFromRes = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.colors)
//int [] colors = new int[colorsFromRes];

for (int i = 0; i < colorsFromRes.lenght; i++) {
    //colors [i]  = Color.parseColor(colorsFromRes[i]);
    tv6.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(colorsFromRes[i]));
}
```

Comment: А string-array нужно поместить в папку values?

Comment: где удобно. Можно в colors.res

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Первый пример прекрасно работает.